# Robospice. How to save data and how to get data from DB?

Tags: java, android, caching, robospice

In project i use `Robispice` and have an issue.
I try to send request

```
getServiceManager().execute(
new GetMessagesRequest(), "ChatItem", DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new GetMessagesResponseListener());
```

but in `GetMessagesResponseListener` has no event happends.

The request below works correctly.

```
 getServiceManager().execute(
 new GetMessagesRequest(), new GetMessagesResponseListener());
```

Also when i try to get data from DB using

```
getServiceManager().getFromCache(...);
```

Nothing happends.What is my problem?